# Why is my moment _i good and moment.format returning my wrong _d

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using moment to do a isBefore of formatted dates but moment is acting funny, first my formating function that might cause the problem:

```
var date =  moment(dateTime.date).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
    var fullDate = date + ' ' + dateTime.time;
    return moment(fullDate, "MMMM do YYYY hh:mm a");
```

i is good and d is bad d is the date of creation (I guess):

```
_d: Tue Mar 01 2016 19:03:00 GMT-0500 (COT)
_f: "MMMM do YYYY hh:mm a"
_i: "March 17th 2016 07:03 PM"
_isAMomentObject: true
```

I want to compare to today : 
    eventDate.isBefore(new Date())

Comment: First off, It's always a good idea to provide all data. When you omit things like `dateTime` we have to assume things and that makes for bad answers. Secondly, why even bother with moment's internal values? There is seldom any need for that. Thirdly, while probably minor I suggest you use `moment()` for "today" as is done in the docs. (You'll inevitably use  `startOf` or maybe `subtract` before you are done anyway). And finally fourth: `do` is not the same thing as `Do` in your format string (could this be your real problem perhaps?).

Comment: " acting funny," is not a suitable statement of your problem. You need to say what data you used, what response you expect and what you get, plus any error messages.

Comment: Underscore prefixed fields are a common JavaScript convention to denote  *internal* usage.  Do not use those fields.  Use the public API.  More in the dup link.